# TFS 2017 custom call TeamFoundationApplication.Log

Tags: c#

I moved my project from TFS 2010 in TFS 2017. But now I am getting an error: [TeamFoundationApplication.Log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg234423(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
TeamFoundationApplication.Log(String.Format("ChangeWIState: {0}; state: {1}", wi.Id, state), 1, EventLogEntryType.Information);
```

> Error1:   CS0012  The type 'HttpApplication' is defined in an assembly that
>   is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>
> Error2:    CS0117  'TeamFoundationApplication' does not contain a >definition for 'Log'What it the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS does not contain  TeamFoundationApplication class from 2012. Try TeamFoundationApplicationCore Class: Log(String, Int32, EventLogEntryType) or LogException(String, Exception)

```js
try {
//some code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    TeamFoundationApplicationCore.LogException("Exception from my code", ex);
}
```

Also you can yse use: [TeamFoundationEventLogger class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server.teamfoundationeventlogger(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much :))

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error, please try below ways to fix that:

- Installing NuGet package [Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg234423(v=vs.100).aspx), run the following command in the Package Manager Console

  `PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 5.2.3`
- Modify the `web.config` like below snippet, add assembly to compilation element:

  `<system.web>
      <authentication mode="None" />
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />`

If that still not work, please try [TeamFoundationApplicationCore Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server.teamfoundationapplicationcore%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [TeamFoundationEventLogger Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.server.teamfoundationeventlogger(v=vs.110).aspx) with the log method [TeamFoundationApplicationCore.Log Method (String, Int32, EventLogEntryType)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj904425(v=vs.110).aspx) or LogException method [LogException(String, Exception)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj904426(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks very much :))